# Isomorphism theorem for several operators

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, linear-transformations, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, and $T_1,T_2$ be linear operators on $V$. When does it hold that $\text{ker}(T_1)\cap\text{ker}(T_2)\cong V/\text{span}\{\text{im}(T_1),\text{im}(T_2)\}$? Here ker and im denote kernel and image resp.

An application of this problem is as follows. Let $A$ be an f.d. semisimple associative algebra. Let $V$ be an f.d. right $A$-module, and $W$ an f.d. left $A$-module. Denote $V\otimes_A W:=V\otimes W/\text{span}\{va\otimes w-v\otimes aw:v\in V,w\in W,a\in A\}$. How can we prove that $V\otimes_A W\cong \{x\in V\otimes W:(a\otimes I-I\otimes a)\cdot x=0\}$? Here $I$ is identity operator.

Thanks!

Comment: The question is related to the application as follows, right? Take a finite basis $\{a_i\}$ of $A$ and let $T_i(v \otimes w)=v a_i \otimes w - v \otimes a_i w$. Then $(V \otimes W)/\sum_i \mathrm{im}(T_i)$ is the tensor product $V \otimes_A W$, and you want to show that it is isomorphic to the subspace $\bigcap_i \ker(T_i)$ of $V \otimes W$. Concerning the general question, even in the case $T_1=T_2$, there is no *canonical* isomorphism $\ker(T_1) \cong V/\mathrm{im}(T_1)$.

Comment: Yes. I do not need a canonical isomorphism.

Comment: I just do not know how to prove and understand the second isomorphism (about the $V\otimes_A W$) in an easy way. You can ignore my first question if it makes no sense. @HeinrichD